# Retrieving all values for a unique key in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have

```
var data = 

[
   {
      "id":"07907313",
      "type":"car",
      "year":"1999"
   },
   {
      "id":"0797096",
      "type":"boat",
      "year":"2013"
   },
   {
      "id":"2341353",
      "type":"plane",
      "year":"2015"
   }
]
```

I do

```
var jsonAsString = JSON.stringify(data); 
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonAsString);
```

I want to pull out each unique keys(id, type, year) values and create another var with the format:

```
[
    {"name": "id", "data": ["07907313","0797096","2341353"]},
    {"name": "type", "data": ["car","boat","plane"]},
    {"name": "year", "data":["1999","2013","2015"]}
]
```

I've struggled getting the output that I want.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want only the unqiue values in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start by walking through each item you have now, pulling out the data, and consolidating it into a single object. Something like so:

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "07907313",
  "type": "car",
  "year": "1999"
}, {
  "id": "0797096",
  "type": "boat",
  "year": "2013"
}, {
  "id": "2341353",
  "type": "plane",
  "year": "2015"
}];

var results = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    results[key] = results[key] || [];
    results[key].push(item[key]);
  });
});

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(results);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks ssube!! This worked great to get the data in the desired format. I was able to use your code and push the values in the format: finalArray.push({"name": key, "data": results[key]});  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to archieve this

```
var res = [{"name": "id", "data": data.map(function (e) {return e.id;})}, 
 {"name": "type", "data": data.map(function (e) {return e.type;})}, 
 {"name": "year", "data": data.map(function (e) {return e.year;})}]
```

You can check out more in 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Regards,

Dan